# Pervent gnome terminal window from closing if unused for too long

Tags: centos, gnome

I'm running gnome in a VM.  I leave the VM up all the time, even when I sign out of VNC.  Lately I have noticed when I come back in the next morning all the terminal windows I had open have closed, presumably due to timing out after a night of inactivity.

I want to prevent this from happening.  I find it annoying to reopen and position my terminals.  more importantly checking what is on my terminals is one of the things that helps me remember what I was doing when I had to log off the night before.  How can I prevent them from closing?

Comment: Are you sure that the VM stays up? You can probably check with `uptime`.

Comment: @Nick  Yes.  My spacemacs windows all stay open.  In addition one terminal window, the one that is usually actively running the program I'm testing, stays open.  I lose all the terminals not actively running applications though.

Comment: Check the journal to see if there's a mention of any cleanup routines closing idle programs. `sudo journalctl -b | grep -i "terminal"` should filter to the terminal emulators since boot.

Comment: The shell can have an idle timeout set, for example env variable `TMOUT` is the number of seconds to wait for a command in bash.

Comment: @meuh  It looks like that was the problem.  I've unset it in my .bashrc, I'll have to wait until tomorrow to see if that worked.  If you want to post this as an answer I'll accept it if that turns out to work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh` shells all interpret the environment variable `TMOUT`, if set to a positive integer, as the maximum number of seconds to wait for a command in an interactive shell before exiting due to idleness. They issue a warning message, but you will not see it as your terminal will disappear. `ksh` seems to provide an extra 60 seconds after the warning.

The same variable is used to set the default timeout for `read` and `select` in `bash` scripts.